# I can't create folder in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have this in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest

RUN mkdir -p /new-folder
```

Since the latests release of the image (07/13/2023), I get this error:

> mkdir: cannot create directory '/new-folder': Permission denied

If I change the image to the previous one (`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-CU5-ubuntu-20.04`) it works well again.

So I have 2 questions:

1. What can I do in my Dockerfile to enable folder creation with the latest image?
2. Is it possible to see the Dockerfile of that SQLServer image, to understand this breaking change?

Comment: As you want to create the folder in the root directory, you'll need to run the command as root as well. Otherwise create the directory somewhere else that isn't the root folder.

Comment: you may want to use `USER root` in your dockerfile. Maybe give it a try if you really need to. But the best solution is of course switching to a directory where you have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not working because `/` is owned by root while you're trying to create a folder with the default user that is the user of the parent image.

You have to create the folder as **root user**:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /newfolder
```

then, if you want to change user, you should:

- add the commands to create a new user
- change the permission of that folder
- set the new user.

In this case, you can re-use the default **mssql user** and add to the Dockerfile the lines:

```
 RUN chown mssql /newfolder
 USER mssql
```

or create a **new user** and use these lines:

```
RUN useradd -r newuser
RUN chown newuser /newfolder
USER newuser
```

Comment: The default user in the image is called `mssql`, so rather than creating a new user, you should change back to the `mssql` user after creating the directory.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated my answer with your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Change WORKDIR to a directory you actually have permission to create folders in.